# Windows or Linux equivalent to Final Cut Pro?

Tags: windows, linux, adobe-premiere, final-cut-pro

I can't believe someone hasn't asked this already...

What are the Windows or Linux equivalents of Final Cut Pro?

Via Google I found some sites discussing this, and several mentioned Adobe Premiere Pro, but none of the links were from this year, or even last year, so I'm looking for something a bit more *current*.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the best place for your question, but anyway...

Do you need a home video editing solution, or a professional tool?

Some may argue whether FCP is truly professional, but anyway it is used as such by many editors. (the latest version X is not quite ready yet for Pro use, but probably will be eventually)

On Linux, there is nothing comparable. At least for now. My main machine is Linux, and I did have a look at a few things like Cinelerra, Kino, Blender, etc. Some of these programs may be good for some specialized task, but none is a serious general purpose video editor.

In Windows, you have the really professional [Avid](http://www.avid.com/US/categories/Professional-Video-Editing-Finishing) systems. The learning curve may be steeper than with Final Cut, but if you envision editing as a profession, you will need to know it anyway.

The semi-professional alternative would be [Adobe Premiere Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html). Here, some may argue that it actually is professional - and it is sometimes used for ads or for some TV programs - but I never heard of feature length movie released in theaters and editied on Premiere. But depending on your needs, it may work well for you.

Finally, for home video editing, there are several other Windows programs (Vegas, etc).

I usually recommend Final Cut Pro, even for people who don't have a Mac and will need to buy one. FCP is relatively easy to begin with, but can still scale to bigger projects. If you don't need the professional features which are missing from the latest FCP X, consider getting that.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of some interest: [Lightworks](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/)

It is out for Linux (open sourced even!) in November and has quite a [list of production credits](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=107&Itemid=260)

Comment: Lightworks may be interesting some day, but as of January 2013, there is only an [announcement](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=19&id=36286&Itemid=81#36286) : "Before the end of the first quarter of 2013 we will be making the Linux version of Lightworks available as a Public Beta".

Comment: As of May 2013 Lightworks is in official public beta, however it has a much steeper learning curve than FCP and it's extensive list of things it can't do yet is a bit intimidating. But like me I hope all linux users interested in video editing will keep their eye on this project.